# How to add time to the output of this max/min select?

Tags: sqlite, date, subquery, window-functions

I have a simple sqlite3 database for recording temperatures,the database schema is trivially simple:-

```
CREATE TABLE temperatures (DateTime, Temperature);
```

To output maximum and minimum temperatures over 1 month I have the following query:-

```
   SELECT datetime, max(temperature), min(temperature) from temperatures 
   WHERE datetime(DateTime) > datetime('now', '-1 month')
   GROUP BY strftime('%d-%m', DateTime)
   ORDER BY DateTime;
```

How can I get the times for maxima and minima as well?  Does it need a sub-query or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use window functions `MIN()`, `MAX()` and `FIRST_VALUE()` instead of aggregation:

```
SELECT DISTINCT date(DateTime) date, 
       MAX(temperature) OVER (PARTITION BY date(DateTime)) max_temperature, 
       FIRST_VALUE(time(datetime)) OVER (PARTITION BY date(DateTime) ORDER BY temperature DESC) time_of_max_temperature,
       MIN(temperature) OVER (PARTITION BY date(DateTime)) min_temperature,
       FIRST_VALUE(time(datetime)) OVER (PARTITION BY date(DateTime) ORDER BY temperature) time_of_min_temperature
FROM temperatures 
WHERE datetime(DateTime) > datetime('now', '-1 month')
ORDER BY date;
```

If your `DateTime` column contains values in the ISO format `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` there is no need for `datetime(DateTime)`.
You can use directly `DateTime`.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you.

The datetime(DateTime) was inherited from some other code where I don't think the column was ISO format.

Anyway, your code works beautifully, thank you!